# Using python to find random comment in json file

Tags: python, json

my json file pretty printed:

```
{u'count': 80,
 u'data': [{u'comment': {u'activity_id': 41638,
                         u'date': u'4/2/2013 11:07:29 PM',
                         u'id': 3230,
                         u'message': u'I echo that.  Thanks for jumping in at any moment without hesitation to take the lead on TMO deliverables; you have improved our relationship with an extremely valuable client.',
                         u'user': {u'first_name': u'Brent',
                                   u'id': 4863,
                                   u'last_name': u'Camalich',
                                   u'picture': u'http://lunchbox.youearnedit.com/profile/4863/image/'}}},
           {u'comment': {u'activity_id': 42577,
                         u'date': u'4/5/2013 12:29:16 AM',
                         u'id': 3384,
                         u'message': u'Thanks Greg!  Go team Gamecenter!',
                         u'user': {u'first_name': u'Malik',
                                   u'id': 7581,
                                   u'last_name': u'Jones',
                                   u'picture': u'http://lunchbox.youearnedit.com/profile/7581/image/'}}},
           {u'comment': {u'activity_id': 42578,
                         u'date': u'4/5/2013 12:29:54 AM',
                         u'id': 3385,
                         u'message': u'Thanks Josh!!  Appreciate the points!  Let me know if you ever need anything.',
                         u'user': {u'first_name': u'Malik',
                                   u'id': 7581,
                                   u'last_name': u'Jones',
                                   u'picture': u'http://lunchbox.youearnedit.com/profile/7581/image/'}}}],
 u'page': 1,
 u'page_count': 4,
 u'page_size': 25}
```

I can return top level parts of the json file like the `count`, `page`, `page_count`, and `page_size` but I'm struggling to get a list of `activity_id`s. After that I was planning on randomly picking from the list to find a comment. Any help is appreciated

```
#!/bin/python

import requests, json
from pprint import pprint

comments_url = "https://lunchbox:9e7cb94db13448209b1a66e71e145b7d@api.youearnedit.com/comments"
r = requests.get(comments_url)

json_data = r.json()

print "Comment Count"
print json_data["count"]

pprint(json_data)

activity_ids = [comment['activity_id'] for comment in json_data[1]['comments']]

for activity_id in activity_ids:
    print activity_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
for item in json_data['data']:
    comment = item['comment']
    print comment['activity_id']
```